# waitForCondition gives missing ; before statement error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've looked at all the examples and I am still have a problem using waitForCondition. Here is my code.

```
WebDriverBackedSelenium seleniumWD = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.x.com");

seleniumWD.waitForCondition("seleniumWD.isElementPresent(\"fullname\");", "5000");
```

I get the error: seleniumWD is not defined. So I changed it to:

```
WebDriverBackedSelenium seleniumWD = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.x.com");

seleniumWD.waitForCondition("boolean ok = seleniumWD.isElementPresent(\"fullname\");", "5000");
```

And now I get the error: missing ; before statement

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the Selenium JS object from the Selenium 2/ WebDriver based test. Instead of using WebDriverBackedSelenium you should use ExpectedCondition and Wait classes provided by WebDriver. In your case, assuming that the `fullname` is the id of the element for which you are waiting, your code should look like this:

```
WebElement element;
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        element = d.findElement(By.id("fullname"));
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
};

Wait<WebDriver> w = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
w.until(e);
```

This is a really big piece of code, so you should consider utilizing the [Page Objects pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) which is a one of the best practices for writing Selenium tests. Example page which contains your field will be something like this:

```
public class MyPage {
    @FindBy(id="fullname")
    private WebElement fullName;

    public MyPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 15), this);
    }

    public void setFullName(String value) {
        fullName.clear();
        fullName.sendKeys(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your code but that doesn't explain why I can't use waitForCondition without getting an error.

Comment: WebDriverBackedSelenium does not have all the methods of the original Selenium interface implemented. One possibility is that the waitForCondition is not done yet or may be is not planned to be implemented because there's API in WebDriver to handle the same purpose.
The other question is what is the JavaScript that you are trying to execute? `seleniumWD.isElementPresent` looks like you are trying to invoke the JS provided by Selenium 1 and it is not available in Se 2